# 3D plot in r of variables from expand grid

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot a 3D plane from three variables. I've read many questions on the topic but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

I have two sets of variables:

```
prob <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
n <- seq(999,9999, by = 1000)
n <- c(9,99,n)
combis <- expand.grid(prob,n)
```

which I then use to produce my results:

```
res <- apply(combis,1,calc,pos=pos)
```

where the values of res can be between 0 and 2/3.

So I'm trying to make a 3d plot where n,prob are x,z and y is res. However most packages I've found require matrices etc, and cannot get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if I haven't found the answer.

Comment: I ended up using the plot3d function to create a scatterplot. With many values it *looked* like a surface. I think the main reason I was having problems is that my values where not continuous so I couldn't get an actual surface. I think there should be something to "predict" values between discrete values to be able to plot a surface(?).

I also used persp3D but the plot made no sense to me. It seemed to be plotting some aggregate form of my data, although I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `res` is just a vector, you can just combine your data and reshape it into a wide-format matrix and then plot with something like the `lattice` package

```
prob <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
n <- seq(999,9999, by = 1000)
n <- c(9,99,n)
combis <- expand.grid(prob,n)

res <- runif(n=nrow(combis), 0, 0.67) #generate sample data for res
dat <- cbind(combis, res)

library(reshape2)
datm <- acast(data = dat, Var1~Var2, value.var = "res") #cast it into wide format

library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

cloud(datm, panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dbars, xlab="n", ylab="res", zlab="prob")
```

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I ended up making a 3 columns (n,p,res) matrix which I used with plot3d for a scatter plot. I'll update my question later tonight as I don't have access to the code right now.